# How to find the co-efficients of a function within Zp[x]?

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves, modular-arithmetic, finite-field, abe

I am a newbie in Finite Field arithmetic and while trying to implement an Elliptic Curve Cryptography based ABE scheme in a programming language, I am unable to understand how to implement function fields.

I am given a function definition within a finite field of $p(i.e. Z_p[x])$ where $p$ is some large prime number. How do I find the co-efficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $f(x)$?

Function definition:
$$f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^3 (x+H(i))^i$$
where, H(k) is a one-way hash function giving a large output.

**Q1**. Since the function is defined in $Z_p[x]$, should all the co-efficient be first calculated using elementary algebra and then taken modulus with $p$?

**Q2**. If we want to calculate the value of $f(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is some constant, can we do it using the final function polynomial of the previous step and substituting all x's with $\alpha$ and then taking a modulus $p$ again?

Comment: I have seen some resources which mention about Galois Field $\operatorname{GF}(p^n)$ and how we find irreducible polynomials of degree $n-1$. In my opinion we should take the $mod$ of the co-efficients and then after evaluating $f(\alpha)$, we will again take $mod$, am I moving in the right direction?

Comment: Please do not provide guesses or followup questions as answers, you can either comment or include some additional information in the question instead.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem as in $\text{GF}(p^n)$, for there is mention of neither the degree $n$, nor of a polynomial acting as a reduction polynomial (which bounded degree would be $n$). I think we are working in the field of polynomials of unbounded degree, with coefficients in $\text{GF}(p)$ (the integers modulo prime $p$).

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can always do in situations like this is "defer the reductions to the end".
By this, I mean do all of your calculations in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and then at the end "perform reductions until you no longer can", where the two kinds of reductions you do in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are:

1. Modular reductions (of coefficients): $a\mapsto a\bmod p$
2. Reductions (of variables) according to [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) (if working mod $n$ for a composite number, instead use [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)): $x^k\mapsto x^{k\bmod \varphi(p)}\bmod p = x^{k\bmod (p-1)}$

As kelalaka points out, you can first expand $f(x)$ as a degree 6 polynomial. As $p$ is large compared to the degree (unless by "large" you mean something like 5), you will need no reductions of the second type, so can solely reduce the coefficients of $f(x)$ mod $p$.

If you have to do these computations on the fly this is not the most efficient thing to do (as the initial computation of $f(x)$ can potentially have a *very* large representation compared to the reduced version, and you may have to do arithmetic with *very* large numbers in computing this), but it can be useful both *conceptually*, and fine when you need to *pre-process* a polynomial (as you do now).

Essentially, arithmetic with polynomials $\bmod n$ can be split into (familiar) integer polynomial arithmetic, followed by applications of the above two reduction rules.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I find the co-efficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $f(x)$?

$$f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^3 (x+H(i))^i$$

Using Wolfram Alpha [try online](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cprod_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E3+%28x%2BH%28i%29%29%5Ei)

$$f(x) = (H(1) + x) (H(2) + x)^2 (H(3) + x)^3$$ and an see the expanded form  there.

This is a one-time job. If the $H$ is defined can be shortened, too. The $H(i)$ values should be reduced into $\pmod p$ before multiplications

$$f(x) = (H(1) \bmod p+ x) (H(2) \bmod p + x)^2 (H(3) \bmod p+ x)^3$$

The $x^k$ over there. With [SageMath Symbolic Coefficients](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/expression.html) you can do it, too. ([try here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwti8EKgDAMQ-_9irKLqxYPikd_ZTDLhIHoEJF-vi14aZq85M137JQzbywdQcMVow6ZersbpclVKM0A7a7nE9so13EUeaISAchVdpssP8XgwY6aAqO_jMGwGd8ZqVKL9TS5I_oAzCIkww==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==))

```
var('x,a,b,c')
p = (x+a)*(x+b)^2*(x+c)^3

print(p.collect(x)) #Collect the coefficients into a group.

coef = 5
print( "coeff x^", coef, " = ", p.coefficient(x^coef))
```

> Q1. Since, the function is defined in $Z_p[x]$, should all the co-efficient be first calculated using elementary algebra and then taken modulus with p?

No, not necessary, you can only need to calculate the ones that contribute $x^k$.

> Q2. If we want to calculate the value of $f(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is some constant, can we do it using the final function polynomial of the previous step and substituting all x's with $\alpha$ and then taking a modulus $p$ again?

First, apply the value of the $\alpha$, then all will be numbers, and calculate each by taking modulo in each step to reduce the multiplication time, This is common like a modular repeated squaring algorithm.

Comment: Suggestion: de-emphasize the expanded form, which makes the answer intimidating. Perhaps, make it a [link to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%5B%28x%2BH%5Bi%5D%29%5Ei%2C%7Bi%2C1%2C3%7D%5D) or a [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/9@1oiAxLyU6oCg/pTS5JFqjQtsjOjNWMy5TpzpTx1DHuDY29v///7oFRZl5JQA). \[update: we can also collect the terms, as asked, see this [better TiO](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/985PycnNbkkOqAoP6UUSGtUaHtEZ8ZqxmXqVGfqGOoY18bqVMT@//9ft6AoM68EAA)\]

Comment: @fgrieu I did. and SageMath has a nice package, too.